# undefined reference to `sin', even though I use <math.h> and -lm

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I noticed that when I use `sin` inside  function the compiler don't recognize it, here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

float sinus(float a){
    return sin(a);}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double a = sinus(2);
    printf("%f \n", sin(2));
    printf("%f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

If I use it directly in main it works fine, but inside a user defined function it gives me this error `undefined reference to sin`.

For compiling I use `gcc -Wall -lm -lc -lgcc  -o "%e" "%f"`.

Comment: What system/environment are you building for? Adding `-lc` and `-lgcc` is almost certainly not necessary... What are `%e` and `%f`?

Comment: I'm using geany in ubuntu and this is the gcc version `gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) `
`%e` is for the filename without .c and `%f` is for the filename.c

Comment: Then @alk's comment is what you're looking for (he/she should write it as an answer).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.
putting the references to libraries in the end resolved it. 
Happy holidays for you all!

Answer (score 6):

References to libraries typically go to the end of the command line, in particular *after* the sources have been specified:

```
gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -lm
```

<sup>(specifing the C lib is not necessary, it is linked implicilty)</sup>

From the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> -l *library*
>
> [...]
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.