# uci_api.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `uci_alloc_context'

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference, openwrt, uci

Getting this error:

```
uci_api.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `uci_alloc_context'
```

while compiling a C file which includes `uci` API like `uci_set uci_alloc_context`, `uci_load` even though I compile with `-luci`. Is there any dependent packages?

Comment: The linker could not find the symbol `uci_alloc_context` A source file or library are missing in the link phase.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie Yes I am missing libuci but how to link it. I used -luci for that reason but thats not correct.

Comment: Please show to whole command you use to compile and link.

Comment: Perhaps this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503982/694576 helps you.